# Is there any API in express to stop http server in code?

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I'm setting up a express server in electron.How can I stop it in a button handler?

can't find a express API for this.

```
// create a express server 
ipcMain.on('create-http-server', (event, data) => {
        const port = data.note;
        isPortAvailable( data.note ).then(() => {
            const test = httpApp.listen( port );
            event.reply('create-http-server-reply',{ result:'success'} );
        })
        .catch( err => {
            event.reply('create-http-server-reply',{ result:'failed',err:err } );
        })
})
ipcMain.on('stop-http-server',(event,data) => {
    // how to stop express server here? 
    console.log( data )
})
```

Comment: Once you have an http server object, you can see the methods for it in the [Net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server).  There's a `server.close()` method that will start the shut-down of the server.

Comment: Thanks! 

`httpServer = expressApp.listen( poart );`

`httpServer.close();`